# Reasons why an web-application on iPad3 iOS6 works "sometimes and sometimes not"?

Tags: javascript, ios, debugging, web-applications, ios6

which is all the user, I'm having to remote debug can tell me... Since I'm also without a device to test for the next couple of days, I'm pretty much in the dark.

The application is a web-app written in javascript/jQuery Mobile and working fine on iPad1+2 and iOS3+4. When the user was instructed, the system worked without problems on his iPad

Now he is stuck on the first page and sometimes "nothing happens", but even when the page works he cannot even log into the system.

**Question:**
Since the application worked fine the first time and I have read there are some new caching mechanisms in iOS, I suspect it could be related to this. However, there is no place to go online when looking for things to be aware of when using script heavy web applications on iOS6.

So, what pitfalls do I have to be aware of when upgrading an application to iOS6?

Comment: may be there is some problem with jQuery mobile compatibility with iOS6

Comment: yes. need to check, that. thanks